# How to remove url

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i< count($resultz[musicshara][link]); $i++) {
    {
        echo'<div class="track"><a href="'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink].'" class="control download" title="\u0421\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0432 TAS-IX">\u0421\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c</a>
                    <a href="#play_'.$i.'" class="control playback play p" title="\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0430\u0442\u044c">\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0430\u0442\u044c</a>
                    <span class="title">'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][artist].' - '.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][s_name].'</span>
                    <span class="length">'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][duration].'</span>
                    <div class="cl"></div></div>
                    ';
    }
}?>
```

---

`'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink].' = http://referer.us/http://stream.get-tune.net` change to http://stream.get-tune.net

Comment: Please let me know if 1st URL will always be http://referer.us ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only one case what you need replace, then use

```
$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink] = str_replace(" http://referer.us/","",$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink]);
```

Other variant is much flexible:

```
$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink] = mb_ereg replace("http://.+(http.+)","\\1",$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink]);
```

You should add my code here :

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i< count($resultz[musicshara][link]); $i++) {
    {
         //here
         $resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink]  = mb_ereg replace("http://.+(http.+)","\\1",$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink]);
         //here
         echo'<div class="track"><a href="'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink].'" class="control download" title="\u0421\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0432 TAS-IX">\u0421\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c</a>
                    <a href="#play_'.$i.'" class="control playback play p" title="\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0430\u0442\u044c">\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0430\u0442\u044c</a>
                    <span class="title">'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][artist].' - '.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][s_name].'</span>
                    <span class="length">'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][duration].'</span>
                    <div class="cl"></div></div>
                    ';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: I can't check now code, but i gave you idea how to solve your problem. Use regular expressions.

Comment: http://musicbox.uz/search.zip download the file. help me!!

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: oh, sorry. There should be mb_ereg_replace :)

Comment: Hi Daggeto help me !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012402/how-add-kcaptcha-to-a-form-of-feedback

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace unwanted text with empty string, try it as per your logic and need.

```
 $str = 'http://referer.us/http://stream.get-tune.net';
 str_replace('http://referer.us/','',$str);
```

Thank you.

Comment: help me ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012402/how-add-kcaptcha-to-a-form-of-feedback

Answer (score 0):

Strip off anything before the last occurrence of 'http://':

```
$url = 'your-url-here'; // $resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink]; etc.
$url = substr($url, strrpos($url, 'http://'));
```

**Additions:**

Yes that does actually work.

You could wrap that in a function like so:

```
<?php

function getActualUrl($url)
{
    return substr($url, strrpos($url, 'http://'));
}
echo getActualUrl('http://referer.us/http://stream.get-tune.net');
// outputs: http://stream.get-tune.net
```

Comment: not working. 
'.$resultz[musicshara][link][$i][slink].' displaying the url http://referer.us/http://stream.get-tune.net/ must to change http://stream.get-tune.net/
please help me !!!